# R extract name of object within purrr::map()

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to extract the names of objects that are being mapped over within purrr::map(). Here's a simplified example of the problem.

```
library(tidyverse)

input <- list(df1 = mtcars, df2 = iris)

map(input, ~ deparse(substitute(.x)))
```

My SO searches led me to the "deparse(subsitute()" trick. But in this example, it returns

```
$df1
[1] "..1"

$df2
[1] "..1"
```

instead of what I want, which is

```
df1
[1] "df1"

$df2
[1] "df2"
```

In other words, I need to be able to process the names of the objects in the list within a more elaborate lambda function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `imap` (which calls `map2` to pass the names index) instead of `map` and extract the `list` names with `.y`  and the values with `.x`.  Here `imap` is calling `map2`

```
library(purrr)
imap(input, ~ .y)
#$df1
#[1] "df1"

#$df2
#[1] "df2"
```

Or instead of `.x`, `.y`, can also use `..1` and `..2`

```
imap(input, ~ ..2)
```

Basically `imap` is calling `map2`

```
 imap
  function (.x, .f, ...) 
 {
.f <- as_mapper(.f, ...)
map2(.x, vec_index(.x), .f, ...)
  }
```

---

If we want to use `map`, option is to loop over the `names` or the sequence of `list`

```
map(names(input), ~ .x)
```

and for subsetting the values, use the `[[`

```
map(names(input), ~ input[[.x]])
```

---

With `map`, the `.x` is only the values of the data and the names of the `list` are not passed into it

---

If we want to use `base R`, then an option is `Map`

```
Map(function(u, v) v, input, names(input))
```

or using `lapply`

```
lapply(names(input), function(nm) nm)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map2` and pass data as well as names.

```
purrr::map2(input, names(input), ~.y)

#$df1
#[1] "df1"

#$df2
#[1] "df2"
```

Here `.x` has the data whereas `.y` has the names of `input`.

The same can be achieved using `Map` in base R :

```
Map(function(x, y) y, input, names(input))
```

where `x` is the data and `y` the names.