# How can I set names of variables in janitor::tabyl using purrr map in R

Tags: r, purrr, janitor

I would like to `purrr::map()` a set of variables to the `tabyl` function from the `janitor` package.  Instead of labeling the variables, `map()` calls everything `.`

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(purrr)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(janitor))

palmerpenguins::penguins |> 
  select(where(~is.factor(.x) | is.character(.x))) |> 
  map(~janitor::tabyl(.))  
#> $species
#>          .   n   percent
#>     Adelie 152 0.4418605
#>  Chinstrap  68 0.1976744
#>     Gentoo 124 0.3604651
#> 
#> $island
#>          .   n   percent
#>     Biscoe 168 0.4883721
#>      Dream 124 0.3604651
#>  Torgersen  52 0.1511628
#> 
#> $sex
#>       .   n    percent valid_percent
#>  female 165 0.47965116     0.4954955
#>    male 168 0.48837209     0.5045045
#>    <NA>  11 0.03197674            NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I think `map()` is naming a vector `.` (but using the real values) as it passes data to `tabyl()`.  Is there a way to tell `map()` to use the original name?  If not, is there an easy way to change the `.` to be the variable name in produced output?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531287/r-extract-name-of-object-within-purrrmap) SO post but I could not get it to behave using `map2()` or `imap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to produce the expected output using `imap`, hopefully not the best:

```r
palmerpenguins::penguins |> 
  select(where(~is.factor(.x) | is.character(.x))) |> 
  imap(~ {dat <- janitor::tabyl(.x)
    names(dat)[1] <- .y
    dat})
```

Comment: Yikes!  That is awesome (and it makes sense) but yikes...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use some [Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) sorcery:

```
palmerpenguins::penguins |> 
  select(where(~is.factor(.x) | is.character(.x))) |> 
  imap(~janitor::tabyl(.x) |> 
         rename(!!.y := 1)
  )
```

Comment: That is some high quality magic.  Thank you!  It makes sense but I think it could make my students explode.